# Can't we use getString() to fetch a date field type from mysql database

Tags: mysql, jdbc

In mysql database, I have a field called `"date"` of `date` type.
When I am trying to retrieve the value in `"date"` field using `getString()` of java
I am getting an exception as thus:

`java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date`

is it that we can't use `getString()` to fetch a date type value? or is the name "date" conflicting with the date field type? or is something else wrong?

`Desc author`

```
Field   Type    Null    Default

date    date    YES     NULL
```

I am just curious about this, thats all. As a solution, I tried converting the `"date"` using `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %m %Y') as dt` and it worked.

Comment: of courrse you should use `getDate();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, when you try to get date from a `ResultSet`, you need to use `getDate` instead of `getString`.

**[SOURCE LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)**

`getString` was able to work on this `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %m %Y')` because its now in the string format.

Comment: use `getInt` to fetch integers

Comment: yes we can use `getInt` to fetch integers, but `getString` also works fine without an exception. But why not in the case of date? However, having said that I know it isn't a good way to use `getString` for integers and dates. I am just curious, thats all.

Comment: The problem is most likely with the MySQL JDBC driver and the content of your columns. I suspect it is not actually `NULL`, but `0000-00-00` instead (which is what MySQL sometimes uses instead of NULL).

Comment: But we have an old program with code segment as follows: rs.**getString("article_date")** from sql statement: **"select article_date from my_topics where ..."** where article_date is of *date* type in the table on **Oracle 8i**. Why doesn't it cause any exception? Could it because of using some 3rd-party Oracle JDBC driver?